# How to install Codeblocks 13.12 on Mint 16

Tags: codeblocks, linux-mint

I am trying to install Code::blocks on Mint16, but newest version in public repo is old (12.11-3). Is there any way of having newest version?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository

Comment: **Other possibility** on download page we can read: NOTE: There are also more recent nightly builds available in the forums or (for Debian and Fedora users) in Jens' Debian repository and Jens' Fedora repository. Please note that we consider nightly builds to be stable, usually. **but this does not work for ubuntu,  so I believe it will not work also for mint**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on reading screenshots on https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ppa/

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3EE66BD3F599ACE3
grep pasgui /etc/apt/sources.list || echo $'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/ppa/ubuntu saucy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/ppa/ubuntu saucy main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update --download-only
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```